# Dialogflow training tab has suddenly stopped displaying user phrases

Tags: dialogflow-es

Training tab that has always shown user phrases is suddenly empty. Support has not responded. Logging out and back in and clearing cache, and exporting/reimporting the agent has done nothing to solve it. Someone else already asked this question here but i can't upvote that one, or comment, and if i star it but they have already moved on because it's fixed for them it's not much help. 
[Dialogflow "Training" menu is empty always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737121/dialogflow-training-menu-is-empty-always)

Has anyone else experienced this and resolved it? We are on standard V2 edition for the last year-ish. Just started being empty last week. We can see questions coming in on the history and analytics tabs but the training tab remains empty. We average 10k questions a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing we could do on our side to fix this. Support finally got us a solution but did not provide any details over what had caused the issue. I asked for more info but all I got was this:

```
Hi Vanessa,

Thanks for reaching out to Dialogflow Support.

There was some internal issue which was resolved. 
We will conduct an internal investigation on the issue and make appropriate
improvements to our systems to help prevent or minimize future recurrence. 
Please accept our apologies for the inconvenience.
```